# Why writing to local storage is async in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

Is there any particular reason in the react native core that forces it to have an `async-storage` rather than a `sync` one?
Because in my point of view writing or reading from local storage should not be a heavy work to do to make it async. I am just comparing it with local storage in web application which we deal with it in a synced way.

Comment: I am not sure. React native apps are seem to be fast enough. I guess it should be something about sending secondary works in an alternative thread instead of the main one.

Answer (score 2):

Writing to local storage require invoking native methods which can only be invoked in an asynchronous way.